# How to make regex of raw string in emacs lisp

Tags: regex, emacs

I am writing my first emacs mode. I am trying to give the `r#"some string inside with "" inside too"#` the `font-lock-string-face` derived from `prog-mode`. I give the `'("r#\\(\".*\"\\)#" 0 font-lock-string-face)`. However, it doesn't work.

How can I make the `r#""#` (from first `"` to the last `"`) the same color as a normal string?

Comment: Have you tried a smaller, very simple string first to make sure it's really the regexp that's the problem, and not something else in your code?

Comment: Yes, I added `("\\(.+\\)=" 1 font-lock-variable-name-face)` and it works fine for the the `var` in expression `var= aaaaa`.